# CodeIgniter: redirect from embed view

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

I have a problem with redirection in embed view.

I'm, working on a project, where security is very important. I use codeigniter and bootstrap. I have main view, which includes navbar and some other html. In that main view i have `<div id="change">` which i am changing via button group. With those buttons I am calling functions in controller with jQuery which (functions in controller) contains `$this->load->view('pages/something', $data);` When i press on one of those buttons `<div id="change">` is changed and in it, a view is shown and link is not changed, so main view remains as it is.

```
<script>
var vari = "<?php echo $data['vari']; ?>";
$(function() {
    $("#btn1").click(function() {
        $("#change").load("Controller/function1/"+vari)
    })
    $("#btn2").click(function() {
        $("#change").load("Controller/function2/"+vari)
    })
    $("#btn3").click(function() {
        $("#change").load("Controller/function3/"+vari)
    })
    $("#btn4").click(function() {
        $("#change").load("Controller/function4/"+vari)
    })
    $("#btn5").click(function() {
        $("#change").load("Controller/function5/"+vari)
    })
})
```

When i do things in one of those embed views, sometimes i want to use `redirect('/Controller', 'refresh');`. Problem is, that when i use it, just embed view is changed - redirected, but main view with navbar and button group is still there.

How can i achieve, that when i call `redirect()` in "embed controller function", main view is changed, not only `<div id="change">`. Is this possible? If not with my method - what could be alternative solution, how can you redirect whole page from "embed controller function" (sorry i dont know how to name this =D).

I will appreciate any help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the user to another page you can use the following

```
var url = 'your/next/page';
$(location).attr('href',url);
```

without using jQuery you can also do

```
window.location.href = url;
```

Comment: It is not exactly what I wanted but it looks like it is the only way =/. Thank you very much! I will try to do it with jq.